# SQL -- IF select A is not in Select B Then Select B else nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a result from SQL:

I have 2 selects:

```
Select columnA from table1;

Select columnA, columnB, columnC from table2;
```

I want to return the second select if all results from select 1 are not like %columnA% of select 2.

Example:
Results from select 1;

```
Hot Dog
Hamburger
Fries
```

Results from Select 2;

```
Shake | Chocolate | 100 cal
Fries | Curly | 200 cal
```

Hoping to get as a result (after if):

```
Shake | Chocolate | 100 cal
```

Comment: I think you can ask a better question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have select2 with its results filtered, so use a where clause:

```
Select columnA, columnB, columnC 
from table2
where columnA not in (select columnA from table1);
```

In case columnA in table1 can be null, you'd have to add `where columnA is not null` to the inner query or use a correlated `not exists` query instead of `not in`.

Here is the same with `not exists`:

```
Select columnA, columnB, columnC 
from table2
where not exists (select * from table1 where table1.columnA = table2.columnA);
```

If you really want to use wildcard matching, change the latter query:

```
Select columnA, columnB, columnC 
from table2 t2
where not exists 
(
  select * 
  from table1 t1
  where t1.columnA like '%' + t2.columnA + '%'
);
```

Comment: Doesn't really give you the wildcard, though - unless the OP doesn't really mean to include those?

Comment: @David T. Macknet: You are right. I missed that. In that case one would have to use `not exists`. I'll add this.

Comment: I prefer the EXISTs because when using N if there is a possiblity of a NULL it will not give you your intended results.  So I like that you added that answer but your where statement still isn't using the like. WHERE table2.ColumnA LIKE + '%' table1.ColumnA + '%'

Comment: @Matt: Thanks. I was just slow typing. I showed the `not exists` query, posted, but then it took me a tad longer than expected to show the complete query with `like`. I still don't know whether the OP is really looking for `like` or whether this was only an unfortunate way to describe "in the set".

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM
    table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t2.ColumnA NOT LIKE '%' + t1.ColumnA + '%'
WHERE
    t1.ColumnA IS NULL
```